# Error on using outer query column in subquery for date constraint

Tags: mysql, subquery, mariadb

We have a Mariadb table with users details in  (users)

We have a 2nd table for review dates (reviewdates)

```
| reviewID |USERID |A review date       |
| 001      | 123   |2017-01-08 09:02:10 |
etc...
```

That records review meeting dates against each user.

We have a 3rd table (userdata) with multiple types of user data in.  Field id 101 is new targets for the review.  Field id 98 is old targets from the previous review.

```
|dataID|Userid |Field ID |FieldValue   |UpdatedOn |UpdatedBy|
-------------------------------------------------------------
|0001  |123    | 101     |my new target|2017-01-10|145      |
|0002  |123    | 98      |my old target|2017-01-10|0        |
```

New Target (field ID 101) gets copied to old targets (field id 98) when the review is completed.

Either field can be updated at any time.

Each user has many review dates.  I need to compare the first value of the old field after the review is complete with the last value before the review date to make sure they have copied over correctly.  As users can change either field it has to a comparison of immediately before and after the completion process.

so I join users and reviewdates

```
select  users.userid,users.username,reviewdates.meetingdate
from companyusers users
join reviewdates on reviewdates.userid = users.userid
```

and this gives me all the review dates for all users

I then tried to find the most recent entry for the 101 field :

```
select  users.userid,users.username, reviewdates.meetingdate, latest101.fielddetails,latest101.updatedon
from users
join reviewdates on reviewdates.userid = users.userid
left join (select userdata.* from userdata u1 
        where u1.fieldid = 101 
        and u1.updatedOn = (select max(u2.updatedon) 
                from userdata u2 
                where u1.userid = u2.userid 
                and u2.fieldid = 101)
                ) as latest101 on (latest101.userid = users.userid)
```

and this works OK too but when I try to find the most recent entry ***before*** each review date:

```
select  users.userid,users.username,reviewdates.meetingdate,latest101.fielddetails,latest101.updatedon
from users
join reviewdates on reviewdates.userid = users.userid
left join (select userdata.* from userdata u1 
        where u1.fieldid = 101 
        and u1.updatedOn = (select max(u2.updatedon) 
            from userdata u2 
            where u1.userid = u2.userid 
            and u2.fieldid = 101
#date limit
            and u2.updatedOn < reviewdates.meetingdate)

            ) as latest101 on (latest101.userid = users.userid)
```

I get an

```
"unknown column reviewdates.meetingdate in where clause"
```

error.  I've found loads of statements saying I can't refer to an outer join in a subquery but none that provide possible answers that apply to these date constraints.

Any help or pointers would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I do not see that you are filtering the most outer 'reveiwdates' table with anything specific, it is just used to display the 'meetingdate' based on the inner queries, 
in that case firstly, there is no reason to use the same reference inside subquery.
Secondly, there are so many 'meetingdates', which specific meeting date are we comparing against the 'updatedOn' ?
You cannot join two tables on an in-equality condition. 
Either a constant review date filter needs be applied or a procedure needs be written to loop through each meeting date for a user in the 'reviewdates' table.

If you just care about the latest review for that user then you could fetch and compare the latest 'reviewdate' just like how you are comparing the latest updated on, 'updatedOn' does not seem to have time component and to avoid other issues use date() or equivalent while comparing.

```
select  users.userid,users.username,reviewdates.meetingdate,latest101.fielddetails,latest101.updatedon
from users
join reviewdates on reviewdates.userid = users.userid
left join (select userdata.* from userdata u1 
    where u1.fieldid = 101 
    and u1.updatedOn = (select max(u2.updatedon) 
        from userdata u2 
        where u1.userid = u2.userid 
        and u2.fieldid = 101
        #date limit
        and u2.updatedOn < (select date(max(reviewdates.meetingdate)) from reviewdates where u2.userid = reviewdates.userid))

        ) as latest101 on (latest101.userid = users.userid)
```

Comment: I don't think I do filter the review date.  I link the users to reviews to get a list of every review date for every user as I need to check the data in the targets fields (101) before and after every review date for every user to prove that the code I've used has been working previously.  I can show its working now but I've been asked to check every existing entry as well.